# my heroku deployment got h10 error can someone look

Tags: rest, heroku, web-applications

I did a one-click deployment of Heroku app from https://github.com/reacherhq/backend

and when I run the app it get this H10 error:

[image: Error-H10]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

That application is configured via [a number of environment variables](https://github.com/reacherhq/backend#configuration). Most are optional, but a `DATABASE_URL` variable is required.

If you [provision a Heroku Postgres database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres), e.g. by running

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

to add a free `hobby-dev` tier database, you'll get a `DATABASE_URL` automatically:

> As part of the provisioning process, a `DATABASE_URL` config var is added to your app’s configuration. `DATABASE_URL` contains the URL your app uses to access the database.

If you prefer to use a different database you can choose from [the available addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) or host elsewhere and manually set `DATABASE_URL`.